# Validate command function for Ctk.Entry that does not accept input if the first character is a number?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am trying to create a validate command function for my Ctk.Entry widget, that does not allow the user to enter an input if the input starts with a number.

For example, can be:

- abcd ef
- abcd123 ab1
- a1b2c3 1c

but can NOT be:

- 1bcd
- 1 abc
- 123abc
- 123 abc

I have succesfully created a 'callback' function for another widget that allows the input to be a number only, works fine, but i am having issues with the function mentioned above. See for code

```
def callback1(P):
'''Perform input validation.

Allow only if does not start with number
'''
    if P.strip() == "":
        return True

    elif P[0].isdigit() ==False:
        return True
```

Here it is registered to the widget(just in case):

```
vcmd1 = (dashboard.register(callback1),"%P")
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: If P[0] is not a digit, I think you need to return True, not False.

Comment: Or, just do `if P[0].isdigit(): return False`. That would be a bit easier to read.

Comment: You are right, i just changed it. However, it prevents to input a number, only if the user tries to do it once, but once it keeps keying in numbers, then it allows them to enter numbers @BryanOakley

Comment: With `P[0].isdigit(): return False`  works fine, but once lets say the input is errased, the function does not work anymore. For exmple, if i go with 'hello' and then delete that and enter '1hello' it allows it. @BryanOakley

Comment: You still have to have the explicit check for the empty string. Also, your function needs to always return True or False. It looks like you don't always return one or the other (ie: there's no final `else` clause or a final return statement after the `if` statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @Bryan Oakley 's help. I figured it out.

First, no need for the indexing inside the `elif` statement, since the function checks for the full input (if the input is a number). And clearly the input will not be a number if started with a letter.

Second, to solve the issue of errasing the input and entering it again, I leave a `return True` at the end of the function so that it keeps running and cheking if input `isdigit()`. It looks like this.

```
def callback1(P):
'''Perform input validation.

Allow only if does not start with number
'''
    if P.strip() == "":
        return True

    elif P.isdigit():
        dashboard.bell()
        return False
    return True #so that the function always runs
```